# Custom drawable background for Android EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-shape

I would like to create a custom drawable background for an `EditText` component in my Android layout. This should include a lower border spanning the entire length of the `EditText`, and 2 connected vertical lines at either end which take up 25% of the height, as per below:

[image: EditText with custom border]

The text itself will then use `android:gravity="left|center"` with a small amount of margin on the left/top/bottom.

I've been able to create a custom border on other input text elements where it was desirable to include all borders using a shape such as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/lightgrey"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

However, now I don't want a full rectangle, only 1 full side + 2 partial sides.

Comment: You should provide the demo image for the desired rectangle

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPNNH.png not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps to achieve that:

- **Keep only the bottom border** by removing the top, right, and left borders by adding negative insets with `android:left|right|top`.
- **Add new rectangle for the side items:** adjust left/right relevant gravity, and limit the height to which size you want (here it's set to 8dp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--    Bottom border -->
    <item
        android:left="-50dp"
        android:right="-50dp"
        android:top="-50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/lightgrey" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <!--    Left border -->
    <item
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="left|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/lightgrey" />
            <size android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--    Right border -->
    <item
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="right|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/lightgrey" />
            <size android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here is the result

[image]